# Does a GAE app keep a log of the emails it sends?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Wondering if it is possible to see a history of emails that a GAE app has sent? Need to look into the history for debugging purposes.

Note that logging when I send the email or bcc'ing a user are not options for this particular question as the period I'm curious about was in the past (since then we are bcc'ing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try one of the following way:

## Log

1. write a log to datastore while each time you call sent_mail.
2. write log with `logging` module and check the log in dashboard.

## mail

1. while send the email, add a debug email address in email's "bcc" field.
2. you can also check the "sent mail" in the email account used as sender.

Comment: both great ideas. we are doing the bcc method but it wasn't setup for the period I'm trying to debug :-( so, was wondering if GAE kept a separate record somewhere.